# Javascript and an image map? How this works?

Tags: javascript, image, imagemap

I have make a image map and have a form. In the form i have three text fields. When i click on the image map. I click on the number 4. The number 4 must come in the text field "regio".

A other example. When i click in the image map on the number 9. The number 9 must come in the textfield "regio".

Here is my code: http://www.testdomeinnaam.nl/mike/

But how can i make this????
Thank you !!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Three things:

1 - for every area you need to attach a firing event.
Way one:

```
<area ... href="JavaScript: regionMap(6); void(0);" >
```

Way two:

```
<area ... onclick="regionMap(6); return false;">
```

Way three:

```
<script>
   jQuery("#imagemap area").click( function(){ 
        var s = jQuery(this).attr("alt");
        regionMap( s.substr(s.length - 2) );
   });
</script>
```

Note that this way takes the number of the region from the `alt` attribute - it's not the best way.

In the first two ways - you have to `void(0)` or `return false` to let the browser know you already handle the event yourself, and that you don't expect it to send the page away because of the user click.

2 - implement the regionMap methoid

Way one - pure JS

```
   function regionMap(region) {
      document.getElementById("regio").value = region;
   }
```

Way two - using jQuery

```
   function regionMap(region) {
      jQuery("#regio").val(region);
   }
```

3 - add the implementation to your page

Way one: embed in your html page code

```
<script>
   function regionMap(region) {
      document.getElementById("regio").value = region;
   }
</script>
```

Way two - use JS resource.
Create a file for example - `regionsform.js`, and in it :

```
   function regionMap(region) {
      document.getElementById("regio").value = region;
   }
```

And embed in your HTML a reference to it.
Assuming the HTML and the regions.js are in the same folder - it would look like

```
<script src="regionsform.js"></script>
```

Have fun & Good luck :)